# How can we avoid the shake when we hover over an element and set it border,over an image and set it border

Tags: jquery

I want to set underline to text on mouse hover and apply borders to image on mouse hover when i do this website is shaking.please tell how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the error, but it sounds like you do not have enough space around your image so when the border gets applied it pushes everything out.

Depending on how many pixels you applied to your border will cause movement in those directions.

If you want to avoid the movement give your divs the same border in its normal state with a transparent color. That way when you apply the hover rule there will be no further movement.

*Quick Edit*

Just to give you an example I have created the following pen - http://codepen.io/mikejayallen/pen/LpEebb

CSS example:

```
#with-invisible-margin {
  border: 5px solid white;
}

#with-invisible-margin:hover {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```